# High frequency limit of dielectric permittivity

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

The electric susceptibility $\chi_e(t)$ of a material is defined via a convolution relation between the polarization field $P$ and the electric field $E$:
$$P(t) = \epsilon_0 (\chi_e * E)(t) =  \epsilon_0 \int_{-\infty}^t \chi_e(t-\tau) E(\tau) d\tau,$$

where $\epsilon_0$ is the electric permittivity of free space. In particular $\chi_e$ vanishes on the negative semiaxis $\mathbb{R}_-$. Taking Fourier transform this relation becomes
$$\hat{P}(\omega) = \epsilon_0 \widehat{\chi_e}(\omega) \hat{E}(\omega)$$

Then one defines the dielectric permittivity of a material as
$$\epsilon(\omega) = \epsilon_0(1+\widehat{\chi_e}(\omega))$$

My question regards to the high frequency limit of this quantity, what I've seen so far is that $\epsilon(\infty) = \epsilon_0$ (e.g. in the plasma limit). This will follow for example when $\chi_e$ is an integrable function then its Fourier Transform has to vanishes as $\omega \to \infty$.

Sorry if my question is trivial, due to my lack of knowledge in physics, but I want to ask is this the only physically meaningful assumption, namely that $\epsilon(\infty) = \epsilon_0$? Does it make sense at all if for example $\epsilon(\infty)=0$? Intuitively I can understand that when the frequency is infinite, the wave probably goes through the material as if it goes through vacuum. I'd appreciate more insight into this.

Answer (score 1):

Electric permittivity is a multiresonant property. Whether there exists something that can reply to infinite frequency I cannot tell, but if you look at a dipole oscillator subjected to an electric field of frequency $\omega$ it yields in the limit of $\omega\to\infty$ the value $0$, which as a result gives $\epsilon = \epsilon_0 (1 + 0) = \epsilon_0$,  identical to vacuum.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong formatting. I was using mobile version of SE where formatting helper is not visible :)